# Can't download Jenkins on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to download and install Jenkins on my VPS after reinstalling the image (Ubuntu 22.04) but I always get an error while trying to download it.

I followed [Jenkins original](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/) guide to get it installed but it's not working.

This is the terminal's output:

```
sudo apt-get install jenkins
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  jenkins
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 92.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 93.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ jenkins 2.375.1
Ign:1 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ jenkins 2.375.1
Ign:1 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ jenkins 2.375.1
Err:1 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ jenkins 2.375.1
  Could not connect to ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de:443 (2a00:8a60:e012:a00::21). - connect (113: No route to host) Could not connect to ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de:443 (137.226.34.46), connection timed out
E: Failed to fetch https://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/jenkins/debian-stable/jenkins_2.375.1_all.deb  Could not connect to ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de:443 (2a00:8a60:e012:a00::21). - connect (113: No route to host) Could not connect to ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de:443 (137.226.34.46), connection timed out
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I've also disabled ufw, but nothing changes. I don't know why after reinstalling a fresh image this is happening when I had no troubles before.

After trying to execute `ping -6c2 ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de` and `ping -4c2 ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de`

I get:

```
root@localhost:/# ping -6c2 ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de
PING ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de(ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de (2a00:8a60:e012:a00::21)) 56 data bytes
From _gateway (fe80::250:56ff:fe8b:8964%ens192) icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address
From _gateway (fe80::250:56ff:fe8b:8964%ens192) icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address

--- ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, +2 errors, 100% packet loss, time 1027ms

root@localhost:/# ping -4c2 ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de
PING ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de (137.226.34.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de (137.226.34.46): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=10.6 ms
64 bytes from ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de (137.226.34.46): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=10.7 ms

--- ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.617/10.680/10.744/0.063 ms
```

I want also specify that I'm connecting to the VPS via SSH.

Even after `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1` I get the same error:

```
root@localhost:/# apt-get install jenkins
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  jenkins
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 92.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 93.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ jenkins 2.375.1
Ign:1 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ jenkins 2.375.1
Ign:1 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ jenkins 2.375.1
Err:1 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ jenkins 2.375.1
  Could not connect to ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de:443 (137.226.34.46), connection timed out
E: Failed to fetch https://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/jenkins/debian-stable/jenkins_2.375.1_all.deb  Could not connect to ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de:443 (137.226.34.46), connection timed out
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried pinging that IP address (137.226.34.46) and it works fine tho.

Comment: Do you have a functioning internet connection? What does `ping -6c2 ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de` and `ping -4c2 ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de` show? [Edit] your question to include the requested information.

Comment: @vidarlo I updated my question

Comment: Looks like you have broken IPv6. Can you run `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1` and retry installation?

Comment: Make Sure having JDK v11 installed for Jenkins later than Jan 2022

Comment: @vidarlo I updated my question

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've already installed JDK 11.0.17 (oct, 2022)

Comment: Does `curl -I https://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/` time out as well?

Comment: @vidarlo, yes it does. `curl: (28) Failed to connect to ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de port 443 after 129238 ms: Connection timed out`